# Parting gifts given by temple

Tags: temple

After big prayer events in temple, we are given half a coconut, banana and a flower as a parting gift. What do I do with these?

Comment: The edibles can be eaten.. actually they are meant to be consumed.. the portions which are still leftover after eating should be immersed in a water body (preferably in a river) like lake etc.. the flower should be made to touch the head (of yourself and others) and then similarly disposed in a river/lake.. some people however keep the flowers in their worship places at homes..they will gradually wither and take a powdered form.

Comment: up to you what you do with them. Most people consume the food items themselves or give the food items to someone who could not come. Many people take the flowers and decorate their own shrines. I've run into some very persistent monkeys on occasion that have insisted the prasadam was theirs and not mine!

Answer (score 3):

These are called [Prasādam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pras%C4%81da). These are of religious importance. These are given to devotees as a blessing from God. Take them to home and eat them. You can also distribute among your friends and family. But don't waste them.  Flowers are to be kept in hair. They are also considered auspicious.

Related question : [Why do we people offer Prasad?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14163/5212)

Comment: What about flowers ? Should we eat that too ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Put them in hair.

Comment: What if a boy took it ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, you can give it to your mom, or sister, or wife. you can also place it on your ear or hair.